# Laravel 4 + AngularJS (AJAX Request)

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs, request, laravel-4

im having a problem retrieving information using my Angular Service from my back end (Laravel 4)
Im just getting error 404

this is my angular service

```
angular.module("SistelApp.Services.ArticleService", [])
    .factory("ArticleService", ["$http", function($http) {

            var doRequest = function(location) {
                return $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: "http://localhost/sistel/" + location + "Service"
                });
            };
            return {
                articles: function(location) {
                    return doRequest(location);
                }
            };
        }]);
```

this is the laravel route:

```
Route::get("/homeService", "HomeController@getArticles");
```

homeController

```
public function getArticles() {

    $array = array();
    $array["name"] = "myName";
    $array["lastname"] = "myLastName";

    return Response::json($array);
}
```

Using Postman (the chrome app) if i go to the route 'HomeService' i succesfully get the data back in json format... but in my angular app i get Error 404 for /HomeService

am i missing something???

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is mistake in your code. You are missing '+':

```
var doRequest = function(location) {
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "http://localhost/sistel/" + location + "Service"
    });
};
```

Comment: o yeah.. that's just a type-O, my code was correct,, im still getting 404 though :P

Comment: Are you sure that your links are correct ? Because you have the /sistel/ which is not visible in `Route::get("/homeService", "HomeController@getArticles");`

Comment: i just red you comment,, yes.. that was basically the problem. ty

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! ... I WAS MISSING SOMETHING...

the url: "`http://localhost/sistel/`" + location + "Service" IS WRONG

because Laravel is routing from "`http://localhost/sistel/public/`

... adding the "public/" fixed my issue.. ty anyway :D